# Drf how to: simple-jwt authenticating without the USERNAME_FIELD

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have extended the TokenObtainPairSerializer, my user model has the email as the USERNAME_FIELD but this type of user does not have an email instead I want to use an auto-generated unique id to authenticate in place of the email.

```
class MyTokenStudentSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = authenticate()(
            student_id=attrs['student_id'], password=attrs['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                data = super().validate(attrs)
                refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
                refresh['student_id'] = self.user.student_id
                try:
                    data["refresh"] = str(refresh)
                    data["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)
                    data['student_id'] = self.user.student_id
                    data['firstname'] = self.user.firstname
                    data['middlename'] = self.user.middlename
                    data['lastname'] = self.user.lastname
                    data['phone'] = self.user.phone
                    data['last_login'] = self.user.last_login
                    data['joined_date'] = self.user.joined_date
                except Exception as e:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(
                        {'error': 'Something Wrong!'})
                return data
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    {'error': 'Account is not activated'})
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'error': 'Incorrect student id and password combination!'})
```

even tho i don't pass an email field this takes email and password, how do i get it to take the student_id instead of the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `username_field` as follows:

Also be careful of using PasswordField, which trims whitespace by default. You definitely do not want `password`    to be valid.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import PasswordField
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class MyTokenStudentSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['student_id'] = serializers.CharField(required=False)
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField(trim_whitespace=False)

    username_field = 'student_id'
    auth_fields = ['student_id']
```

Comment: it worked but how do i pass the additional data with the response like you see in my question?

Comment: You can accumulate the results in a custom Serializer, for example: `student = StudentSerializer(user_obj).data` to nest the results.

Comment: can you show me more code please, or maybe tell me what the (user_obj) does and how to get the data from the serialized fields

Comment: The trick is to nest a serializer. For more reference head [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)